# Display count of characters repeated in a string using SQL only

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to achieve below code snippet o/p using select query alone. Is it possible without using regexp?

```
    Character Count when string input is dynamic.

    DECLARE
      str     VARCHAR2(255);
      lv_val  NUMBER;
      lv_char CHAR(1);
      lv_unq  VARCHAR2(255);
    BEGIN
      str:= :p_string;
      FOR i IN 1..length(str)
      LOOP
        lv_val  := 0;
        lv_char := SUBSTR(str,i,1);
        IF instr(lv_unq,lv_char)>0 THEN
          NULL;
        ELSE
          lv_unq := lv_unq||lv_char;
          lv_val := ((LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(replace(str,' ',''), lv_char, ''))) / LENGTH(lv_char));
          --select  ((length(str) - LENgth(REPLACE(str, lv_char, ''))) / LENgth(lv_char)) into lv_val FROM dual;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Character '||lv_char || ' is repeated :'||lv_val||' times in the string '||str);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: It would be better if you show sample strings and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the question's title:

> Display count of characters repeated in a string using SQL only

```
with v as (select substr('hello world', level, 1) c from dual connect by level < 12),
     d as (select chr(ascii('a')+level-1) c from dual connect by level <= 26)

select d.c, count(v.c) from d left join v on d.c = v.c
group by d.c
order by d.c;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38321/0 for the result

The first view split your string into characters. The second view is just the alphabet. Once you have both views, you only need a simple `left join` with a `group by` clause to count the number of matching occurrences.

Please note:

- in the first view, the string and its length are hard-coded in this example
- I assume all your characters are lower-case
- I only take into account the 26 (lower case) letters of the ASCII encoding.